# Replace dots and special characters in the file name before moving it to another location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a requirement to move the files by creating a new folder. For this below is the code written. this is working perfectly fine.

But code fails when file name contains extra dots, spaces and special characters (such as parenthesis).

Request you to please let me know how to replace/rename the dots, spaces and special characters before moving the file to the target location.

```
if not exist "D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017" mkdir D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
move D:\%2 D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

Note: %2 is the file name being passed to the bat file from triggering procedure.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's no reason that extra periods would ever have that affect on your script. Spaces, sure, but not periods. Always wrap all file paths in quotes.

Comment: @SomethingDark - but the quotes are needed in the calling code, not necessarily within the move script. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46864937/1012053)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put quotes around the names:

```
move "D:\%~2" "D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is not within your "move" script, but rather within the code that is calling the "move" script.

Whenever you pass a string literal that may contain token delimiters like `<space>`, `<tab>`, `=`, `;`, `,`, or special characters like `&` etc., then you should enclose the argument within quotes.

Suppose your script is called `moveFile.bat`, and you want to move `c:\some path with spaces\yourFile`, then your call should look like:

```
call moveFile arg1 "some path with spaces\yourFile"
```

Your script will then properly execute

```
move D:\"some path with spaces\yourFile" D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

If you neglect to quote the argument, then `%2` will be parsed as `c:\some`, and of course that will not work.

Some would argue that you should use `%~2` to remove any existing enclosing quotes, and then explicitly add your own around the entire path, as in

```
move "D:\%~2" D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

In which case the executed command becomes a more familiar looking

```
move "D:\some path with spaces\yourFile" D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

That certainly works just as well, but it is not necessary.

There is one potential problem with the overall design - it cannot support paths that contain both spaces and carets (^) because the path must be quoted, but the CALL statement will effectively double all quoted carets.

so `call moveFile arg1 "some path with spaces\A^B.txt"` will result in the following:

```
move D:\"some path with spaces\A^^B.txt" D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

There is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent the quoted caret doubling
when you use CALL. The best option is to pass your paths by reference as a variable name. Obviously this requires changing moveFile.bat:

Here are the needed modifications to moveFile.bat:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017" mkdir D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
move "D:\!%2!" D:\KUMAR_398519667_9262017
```

And your code that calls moveFile should look like:

```
set "myFile=some path with spaces\A^B"
call moveFile arg1 myFile
```

Comment: Hi dbenham, thanks for the detailed reply it seems to be problem with calling procedure, i am calling the bat file from Siebel escript. After adding the double quotes into the bat file script, it is working fine on running it over cmd as well as double click. But the same is not working when trying to execute the bat file from siebel script. Siebel code is as follows

Comment: Siebel code is as follows   "batstatus = Clib.system("D:\\MoveFiles.bat"+" "+sDestDir+" "+sUnCompFilePath);" where sDesDir is the target directory argument and sUnCompFilePath is the file path. Thank You.

Comment: @Kumar - Try building the complete string within Siebel and printing it out to the screen or file, without executing. Once you get the correct syntax, then pass that string to `Clib.system()`.